Estimate population relative standard deviation from noisy sample
We would like to estimate the relative standard deviation (the standard deviation divided by the mean) of a random variable $X$ defined on a population by measuring a small sample.
The problem is that the measuring method is rather noisy. Typically, it seems like the measurement error could be modeled as $\Delta x = kx + b + \varepsilon$, where $x$ is the true value, $\Delta x$ is the measured value minus the true value and $\varepsilon$ is a random number which is approximately normal distributed.
On average it seems like $\Delta x$ is close to zero, but as the coefficient $k$ is slightly negative, just taking relative standard deviation of a measured sample will typically lead to a slight under-estimation of the population relative standard deviation, even in presence of the noise term $\varepsilon$.
Question: Is there a method for estimating the population relative standard deviation in an unbiased way; that is, a way to compensate for $k$, $b$ and $\varepsilon$ which could be obtained by calibrating the measurement method. Also it would be interesting to get something like a confidence interval (or a distribution) for the estimate. The method could be numerical or be based on some bootstrapping procedure.
In the application, the population relative standard deviation is typically in the range 10%-50% and the standard deviation of $\varepsilon$ is typically 10% of the mean of $x$.
